# Insert into table with foreign keys?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

On my `Addcar` view I have form allow me to insert data into my database (into table `Car`).

In the table `Car` I Have `colonne (Idcat)` it's foreign key related to the `Categorie` table.

So in my add forms I should have a dropDownlist that allow user to chose what's categorie of car he want to add.

this is part of my view :

```
             <div class="editor-label">
    <p>
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Idcat) %>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    <p>
    <!-- in this dropDownList i want to show the all Name Of Marque in my forgien table and user when he select value wil be set at id of selected marque -->
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Idcat, ViewBag.cat as SelectList)%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Idcat) %>
    </p>
    </div>
```

This is my controller action :

```
        public ActionResult addcar()
    {

        ViewBag.cat = new SelectList(entity.categorie, "Idcat", "Nom"); 

        return View();
    }
```

This work fine until i clic on create he show me this error `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable <SelectListItem>' with key 'Idcat'.` at This Line `<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Idcat, ViewBag.cat as SelectList)%>`

Comment: i have updated my post please check it.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASP.Net MusicStore Tutorial there is an example where you choose from a given list of genres. The list of genres is passed to the view via the viewbag that is filled by the controller:

[MusicStore Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5)

This is probably exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: The tutorial is very clear about this. See sections "Passing information to a View using ViewBag" and "HTML Helpers to display the Drop Downs in the Create View". In your case, you will have to get all available marques in the controller, pass it to the view and build the list from that list. If this is not what you need, then be more specific.

Comment: I'cant pass more than one Model to my view, and my view is already using Models.Cars so i'cant pass to it another model

Comment: i didn't get the point, sorry but bigner and this is my first app.

Comment: Then you should follow the tutorial or another. The viewbag is a container that allows a controller to pass additional information to the view. It can be accessed by the ViewBag variable. Since it is a dynamic variable, you can set arbitrary variables on it. If you have the list of marques in your controller, set this list to a member of the viewbag. Then, in the view, the dropdown is created from this list if you specify its name. It's all in the sections of the tutorial. Just read it.

Comment: I'm not useg razor, i use  simple ASPX page

Comment: Razor is just another syntax for the view files. Controllers are equal. Furthermore, it should be easy to convert Razor syntax to ASPX. Mostly, it is about changing @.. to <% .. %>. Just try it.

Comment: but this exmple to show list, and i want to create dropdownlist that contien my list of marque

Comment: You can pass the list in the ViewBag as stated.  Or you can make a view model that is composed of a Cars model and an IEnumerable<Marque>.

Comment: I have updated my post please check it, and ViewBag work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Model binding really only binds individual elements.  So it's fine binding Idmarque.  It is no help displaying a drop down list of possible values.  To me it seems like something lacking in the framework, because it makes you stop using EditorForModel.  You have to decide how you want to handle getting the dropdownlist.  Are you ok with having an Html Helper that will query the database and draw a list of options?  Or would you prefer to have your controller call a model method to get a list of options, and pass that into the view as part of a view model?  Probably want to avoid passing a datareader since you may have open connection issues if you do that.